# Responsive Design with 100% width

Tags: responsive-design, width

I've been researching responsive design recently and had the thought why not use a flow layout instead of something like a 960 grid?  From my research, 960 was chosen to fit the most popular monitor size.  But on larger or wide screen monitors, there is still a lot of empty space.

The thought I had is shouldn't the largest size for media query be 100% page width? Instead of 960 px?

Can anyone explain why this isn't the norm, or why people default to a fixed width for responsive design?

Comment: Depends a lot on the website and desired layout.  Fixed width allows you to control things much more cleanly.  For example, when you have columns of text, you want to keep the column width below around 500px (depending on font size) in order for it to be readable (wider than that, and the eye can't track.  Also, are all of your images going to stretch, or are they fixed width also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use widths wider than 960px, then the [Bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com) is one option, so you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Bootstrap 3 is in the process of being released and while the grid classes have changed you can still get responsive full page layouts or responsive layouts with a max width of 1200px

An example of a [full page grid](http://www.bootply.com/panchroma/74112)
An example of a [max 1200px grid](http://www.bootply.com/74113)

[Foudation](http://foundation.zurb.com) used to have max grid options around 1100px though as far as I can tell, out of the box with Foundation 4 the max is now around 1000px. It should be easy enough to change this though by using a custom setting for the width of the .row class

As for your question

> The thought I had is shouldn't the largest size for media query be 100% page width? Instead of 960 px?

as [@cale_b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/870729/cale-b) noted, readability could be an issue with full width layouts unless you are carefull with typography and font sizes. I think it is certainly doable if you are careful with the design though.

It will depend on the site design.

Good luck!